# remove current path portion from each line in a text file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a bash script which generates text file. But I want to delete current path portion from each line. I tried to run "cut -d'/' 
--complement -s -f1-4" command. But I want some dynamic way to do it. Can someone please help me with it? Thank you !

Sample text file:

```
/local/name1/test/dir/file1.c
/local/name1/test/dir/subdir/file2.h
/local/name1/test/dir2/file3.txt
```

Current path:

```
/local/name1/test/
```

Expected Result:

```
dir/file1.c
dir/subdir/file2.h
dir2/file3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed you can do:

```
sed 's~^/local/name1/test/~~' file

dir/file1.c
dir/subdir/file2.h
dir2/file3.txt
```

If your current path is saved in a variable `p` then use:

```
sed "s~^$p~~" file
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. It works fine. But It still gives one extra slash in the beginning.

Comment: I've shown output of sed in my answer and I'm not getting any leading slash. Make sure you have a trailing slash  in variable `p`.

Comment: Yes. I added back slash in my path var. Now it's working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PWD` and `bash` parameter expansion to get the dynamic behavior:

```
"${var#$PWD/}"
```

Save the file path as `var` first. Here `$PWD` will expand to the current working directory and parameter expansion will get the portion of the file name after the `$PWD`.

**Example:**

```
$ var=/home/foobar/spam/foo/bar.c
$ echo "${var#$PWD/}"
foo/bar.c
```

Comment: Thanks @heemayl for prompt reply and help.